# Is olap necessary for business intelligence?

Tags: data-warehouse, business-intelligence, cube

With the rise of modern data visualization tools like Power BI, are `OLAP` cubes antiquated?  Other than the semantic layer that cubes can provide (i.e., define a measure only once to ensure consistency across reports), I don't understand the value-add of building cubes.  In my experience, putting a tool like Power BI right on top of a data warehouse is just fine.

Comment: Up until recently, for large datasets it was necessary to create SSAS Tabular, which isn't strictly a "cube" as such but from the outside it serves the same purpose. Now that Tabular model can usually be built internally within Power BI, you're right you don't need a cube (until you hit Power BI storage or functional limits). I certainly don't see a lot of use for traditional Multidimensional OLAP cubes like SSAS Multidimensional or Cognos anymore. Sometime cubes were actually used as the layer that mapped OLTP to a dimensional model (without a relational dimensional model in the middle)

Comment: Just keep in mind that enterprise features like partitioned loads and very large data sizes aren't supported in Power BI models directly.